# python: Importing scipy.io seems to prevent sys.exit() to work properly

Tags: python, import

Under Windows, executing the following Python script I get an ERRORLEVEL of 0 instead of the expected 2.

```
import sys
import scipy.io

sys.exit(2)
```

If I remove the import scipy.io, I got the correct ERRORLEVEL of 2...

Any idea why importing scipy.io cause such an issue?

PS: windows 7, python 2.72, scipy 0.10.1

Calling help(sys.exit) just before the sys.exit call return the following (which seems to be good):

```
Help on built-in function exit in module sys: 

exit(...) 
    exit([status]) 

    Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status). 
    If the status is omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success). 
    If the status is numeric, it will be used as the system exit status. 
    If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system 
    exit status will be one (i.e., failure).
```

If I call

```
sys.exit('Something wrong')
```

The string is printed but the system still return 0 as ERRORLEVEL instead of the 1 expected.

Comment: For me it works correctly on python 2.6, Centos 5

Comment: @moooeeeep Calling help(sys.exit) just before the sys.exit call return: `Help on built-in function exit in module sys:

exit(...)
    exit([status])

    Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).
    If the status is omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success).
    If the status is numeric, it will be used as the system exit status.
    If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system
    exit status will be one (i.e., failure).`

Comment: @moooeeeep The string is printed but the system still return 0 as ERRORLEVEL instead of the 1 expected.

Comment: works correctly with python 2.6, Ubuntu Lucid

Comment: works as expected also for Python 2.7, Fedora 16, and Python 2.6, Ubuntu Oneiric.

Comment: I wonder if SciPy is setting up an exit hook that somehow gets in the way. Could you `import atexit` and then print out `atexit._exithandlers` **both before and after** importing `scipy.io`?

Comment: Issue solved or at least workaround found (see answer below)... Thanks all for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to a bug in SciPy. Here are some relevant tickets (only the first one is still open):

- http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1314
- http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1521
- http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1485

One curious observation there is that

> the bug disappears when importing weave.

Perhaps try importing `scipy.weave` to see if this workaround helps?